# Algorithms to reconstruct surface(s) to G2/G3 continuity

Tags: algorithm, bspline

Is there any algorithm/research papers to automatically reconstruct arbitrary surfaces into G2/G3 continuous?

Comment: simply use higher degree spline ... degree of splines/polunomial ensure continuity ...

Comment: @Spektre Nah, it'll create too many unnecessary cvs.